# Mathematical Rebus

Tags: mathematics, rebus

[Mathematical Rebus II](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16514/mathematical-rebus-ii)

[Mathematical Rebus III](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52759/12165)

---

$$
4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\\
(-\infty,...,-1,0,1,...,\infty)\times(-\infty,...,-1,0,1,...,\infty)\\
\forall\begin{bmatrix}{-1}&{0}\\
 {0}&{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This is beautiful! I think I've half-realized the solution, though there's a piece that's giving me a hard time!

Comment: nice one. i think i've got everything except for the matrix. that's the part giving me a headache

Comment: This definitely involves some circular reasoning, but I also haven't figured out the right way to read the matrix.

Comment: Try to identify the Matrix.

Comment: Really , nice one!

Comment: Perfect puzzle! +1

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The first line is

> equal to Pi.

The second line is

> the integers, **Z**, multiplied by itself, making **Z**<sup>2</sup>.

The third line is

> multiplying some matrix ∀ by the negative identity matrix, negating its value. The letter ∀ negated is A.

All together,

> Pi + Z<sup>2</sup> + A = **Pizza**.

Comment: Wow, the last line was very lateral-thinking! I really couldn't realize the meaning of "for every point reflection"

Comment: When I thought about using the Matrix for making $\forall$ become A, I thought about the 180º rotation Matrix.

Comment: Ah! Rotation. I figured there was a more specific term than "negating". I should have been thinking more geometrically.

Comment: Surely if you're applying a rotation matrix to $\forall$, the matrix ought to be placed *before* the $\forall$.

Comment: @DavidZhang - $\forall$ must be a row vector, I guess.