# Mathematical Rebus II

Tags: mathematics, rebus

[Mathematical Rebus I](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15862/mathematical-rebus)

[Mathematical Rebus III](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52759/12165)

---

[image: Rebus' image]

$$\det\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\varphi)}\\
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ddot{\frac{t^n}{n!}} $$

Comment: Now I've the dilemma of whom to give the Correct Answer.

Comment: If there are multiple answers that both give thorough and accurate answers, then go by timestamp. Point to the word "ago" in "answered x hours ago" and you will see the exact time posted. If in a strange case the answers were posted in the same minute, then I like to give the points to the person who is newer to the site, and probably doesn't have a lot of rep points.

Comment: The problem here is that it was half-solved by each. Though I like giving it to the one that's the newest.

Comment: +1 nice puzzle! There's a certain beauty in not needing to have any words or explanation.

Comment: I spent way too long uselessly determining that the function in the graph is approximately `sec(x-2.2)` and I couldn't figure out why it was important. I wish you had done `sec(x)` instead =\ ... +1 anyway for creativity

Comment: I took it from Google since I had nothing to create the graph myself from where I posted the question. Sorry for the inconvenience, Sabre.

Comment: @Sabre I tried to solve it for future solvers

Comment: I think these puzzles are the perfect puzzles to showcase our site - rebuses are well-known and typically pretty simple, but of course we at PSE put our own insane twist on them. Easy peasy +1!

Comment: @Albert Now it's perfect!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Follow up to rand al'thor answer

The graph shows:

> sec(x)

By combining the 2 other answers, we obtain:

> sec + r + et = $secret$

Answer (score 19):

Graph:

> work in progress...

$\det\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\varphi)}=r$, because

> $x,y$ are Cartesian coordinates and $r,\varphi$ are polar coordinates, in the 2-dimensional plane.

$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \ddot{\frac{t^n}{n!}}=e^t$, because

> differentiate $t^n$ twice to get $n(n-1)t^{n-2}$, so the sum is $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \ddot{\frac{t^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ddot{\frac{t^n}{n!}}=e^t$.