# Mathematical Rebus III

Tags: mathematics, rebus

[Mathematical Rebus I](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15862/12165)

[Mathematical Rebus II](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16514/12165)

---

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

[image: Third Image]

---

*Small note on the first image:*

> I wish romans had a number for 0.

Hint 1 for the squares image:

> It is mostly an arithmetic problem.

Hint 2 for the squares image:

> Color and relative position matter.

Hint 3 for the squares image (alternative image that should help a little bit):

> [image: Image Hint]

Hint 4 for the squares image:

> This is a Mathematical Rebus, so what about changing the squares by numbers? Which? It's your work to discover.

Comment: You could avoid needing a zero by summing from I to M and then subtracting I inside the summand.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm aware of that. I considered simply starting at I and summing a to it all. Even though, I felt this way made it easier to solve, so I choosed to keep it this way. Plus I wanted to make sure I was using a number that's clearly a number (like CMXCIX).

Comment: Seems the Rebus got lost without the correct answer being found :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this remains unsolved, I proceed to answer the question.

Most of it had been solved, so I only put together the already given answers and add the missing clue.

First clue, by [Gareth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan):

> is 0 when a=0 and increases by 1 each time a increases by 0.001. So it's floor(1000a) which, given all the Roman numerals, I should probably write as $\lfloor Ma\rfloor$.

Second clue:

> The trick is using the colors. White is #FFFFFF and yellow #FFFF00.
>  It was intended to be FFFFFF module FFFF00, or $FFFFFF_{FFFF00}=FFFFFF \mod FFFF00 \equiv FF$

Third clue, also by [Gareth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan):

> is probably "voltage, in volts, over resistance, in ohms", yielding "current, in amps" or $I_A$.

All together, the answer is:

> **Maffia**, as actually [Gareth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan) already got.

Comment: Following advices on [Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6365/answer-to-your-own-question/6367#6367) I choose my own answer as best in case somebody else wants to use this rebus in the future.
Even though I'd like to note that Gareth solved most of the puzzle.

Comment: What in the second clue indicates "modulo"? (The subscript? I don't think I've ever seen subscripts used that way before.)

Comment: When working on the set Z/nZ (for mod n) is not that rare to use such notation. I'm sorry you feel it was a **very** weird notation. I tried to point into the right direction through Hin 3.

Comment: This link from Wikipedia shows the use I'm refering to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n

Comment: I suppose it does. I'm a mathematician and don't recall ever seeing that notation before; I wonder whether whoever wrote that bit of the Wikipedia page just made it up.

Comment: (I'm not implying that there'd be anything wrong with that, by the way; making up notation for local convenience is a perfectly good thing to do.)

Answer (score 5):

The first expression

> is 0 when a=0 and increases by 1 each time a increases by 0.001. So it's floor(1000a) which, given all the Roman numerals, I should probably write as $\lfloor Ma\rfloor$.

The yellow square

> is about 0.61 times the size of the white one. Perhaps this is hinting at the golden ratio (often written $\varphi$ or $\tau$) but there might be some further thing I'm missing.

The fraction at the end

> is probably "voltage, in volts, over resistance, in ohms", yielding "current, in amps" or $I_A$.

So perhaps we are looking at

> $\lfloor Ma\rfloor\varphi I_A$ or the Mafia. Eek! (The Mafia would fit quite well with the two earlier answers of PIZZA and SECRET, of course.)

[EDITED to add:] OP indicates that I don't have the intended interpretation of the yellow square, so here is another possibility:

> In WYSIWYG equation editors, you often see something very much like this (though much smaller) to indicate a subscript. E.g., this is what the relevant menu item in Word's equation editor looks like: [image: subscript] and this is what you get when you move your cursor into the subscript: [image: selected subscript]. In that case, this could indicate SUB, making our final answer MASUBIA, the name of a group of people in central Africa.

and another:

> if, as above, it's denoting a subscript, perhaps we should replace it with something that commonly appears in subscript position. The most obvious things would be $i,j,k$ but none of those makes a word -- but $n$ yields MANIA, which seems at least kind possible.

I confess that neither seems terribly likely.

Comment: I find it really funny that you got the that letter which would sound like that. Even though, that part is not correct.  If their ratio is really near that must be because doing it manually made them look more beautiful.

Comment: I'd point out that we have k incrementing in the summation, not a. So if the M in the summation is 1000, we have floor(a+x), where x=k/M and is always less than 1, so we're really just summing a 1000 times. (This might be different than the original, given the last edit time.) Same potential result but different reasoning.

Comment: @Duncan Note that *a* need not be an integer.

Comment: Ah, an excellent point. Hate it when I make assumptions.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan by the way, the reason to keep the 0 was to be as faithful as possible to Hermite's identity.

Comment: Sure, but it's the exact same identity whichever way you express it :-).

Answer (score 5):

Building on [Gareth McCaughan's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52760/19989)

> The first part yields **Ma** as Gareth explained.
>  The second part, the squares... the small square is just a variation of the first square. The differences are the size and the color. So this can be a "**thematic**" difference between the 2 squares.
>  The third part yields **A** (again as Gareth says).

Put them together and you get

> **Mathematica**

Comment: Clever but gosh, I hope that isn't the intended answer...

Comment: It is not. It's way more specific and mathematics-related.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans. I thought so, but this fit very nicely and gave me a warm feeling. :)